# want to buiild fruit ninja type slice effect

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to use a code that draws Fruit Ninja style swiping effect using the code at https://github.com/hiepnd/CCBlade

When Compiling I get error at the line #include < list >

(CCBlade.h:14:0 CCBlade.h:14:15: error: list: No such file or directory)

It works fine when integrated with a .m file, but the error is when trying to use it with .mm

Any solutions for this ?

Answer (score 2):

Did you correctly adjust build setup for compiler? In order to compile c++ source code, you need to change compiler properly in build option.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following if you are using Xcode 4.2:

## 1. Click on the CCBlade.m file.

## 2. Look to the right panel (first panel is all your project files, middle panel is your codes and the last panel is the properties).

## 3. On the Identity and Type, select "Objective C++ Type" for the File Type.

## 4. Vice-versa for TouchTrailLayer.m.

Hope that helps!

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works ! Cool, could you please tell me, what was the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting errors '*inline function declared but never defined'* when trying to build the project. This is due to inline C functions in the CCBlade class.

The solution to fix this is simple, rename all classes that use CCBlade with .mm file extension(Objective-C++ files). This fixes the errors.